# How to use boost::python raw_function without getting warning C4267?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I'm using boost 1.82, and if I use `boost::python::raw_function`, I get warning C4267 even if I explicitly use size_t.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

#include <iostream>

boost::python::object Speak(boost::python::tuple args, boost::python::dict kwargs) {
    std::cout << "Test Speak!\n";
    return boost::python::object();
}

class Test {
public:
    Test() {}
};

void RegisterFuncs() {
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<Test>("Test", no_init)
         .def("Speak", raw_function(&Speak, std::size_t{ 2 }));
}

int main()
{
    RegisterFuncs();
}
```

I get this warning:

```
Boost\include\boost-1_82\boost\python\raw_function.hpp(53,13): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
main.cpp(19,24): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::python::api::object boost::python::raw_function<boost::python::api::object(__cdecl *)(boost::python::tuple,boost::python::dict)>(F,size_t)' being compiled
        with
        [
            F=boost::python::api::object (__cdecl *)(boost::python::tuple,boost::python::dict)
        ]
```

I could understand getting this warning if I was doing something like `raw_function(&Speak, 2));`, but I can't understand how this warning is here even if I explicitly pass in a size_t. This also gives the same warning:

```
std::size_t two{ 2 };

class_<Test>("Test", no_init)
     .def("Speak", raw_function(&Speak, two));
```

I can disable the warning with `#pragma`, but I'd rather understand how it's possible that this warning is present and not need to use `#pragma`.

I'm using Visual studio 2022 with `/std:c++latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in your code and nothing you can do to avoid the warning (besides changing the library code or `#pragma` the warning away). The problem is in `raw_function` itself:

([boost/python/raw_function.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/boost/python/raw_function.hpp))

```
template <class F>
object raw_function(F f, std::size_t min_args = 0)
{
    return detail::make_raw_function(
        objects::py_function(
            detail::raw_dispatcher<F>(f)
          , mpl::vector1<PyObject*>()
          , min_args
          , (std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max)()
        )
    );
}
```

`min_args`, which is the `size_t` you pass in your (correct) code, is passed to `py_function` constructor accepting an `int` in that position (`min_arity`):

([boost/python/object/py_function.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp))

```
struct py_function {
    // ...
    template <class Caller, class Sig>
        py_function(Caller const& caller, Sig, int min_arity, int max_arity = 0)
          : m_impl(new full_py_function_impl<Caller, Sig>(caller, min_arity, max_arity))
        {}
    // ...
}
```

The links to files above are for Boost 1.82.0 which you use, but for current version (1.84.0) the situation is the same.

This seems to be not the only problem with mismatch of integral types in Boost.Python, e.g. there's [this issue](https://github.com/boostorg/python/issues/184) still open on GitHub.

Comment: Ugh, I was worried this would be the case. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

```
Boost\include\boost-1_82\boost\python\raw_function.hpp(53,13): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
main.cpp(19,24): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::python::api::object boost::python::raw_function<boost::python::api::object(__cdecl *)(boost::python::tuple,boost::python::dict)>(F,size_t)' being compiled
        with
        [
            F=boost::python::api::object (__cdecl *)(boost::python::tuple,boost::python::dict)
        ]
```

You read errors from top down, so the error happens in the boost header file, out of your control.

What you *can* do is to `#pragma` the error away only in the header file, leaving it active for the rest of the code:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4267)
#include "..."
#pragma warning(pop)
```